# Why can't gcc reduce an if inside a loop

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to understand what GCC can optimize in some fictional code.
In the C code function `b()` should be a semantically equivalent rewrite of `a()`.
As seen in the assembler output `b()` is reduced to a single `puts()`, while `a()` is not and still contains loops.
How comes it that GCC can't apply the same optimizations to `a()` as to `b()`?

C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void a(){
    unsigned int c = 0;
    for(unsigned int a = 0; a < UINT_MAX; a++){
        if(a == (UINT_MAX/2)){
            puts("50");
        }
        c++;
    }
}

static void b(){
    unsigned int b = 0, c = 0;
    for(; b<(UINT_MAX/2); b++){
        c++;
    }
    puts("50");
    for(; b < UINT_MAX; b++){
        c++;
    }
}

int main(){
    a();
    b();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc 4.8.1

```
gcc -std=c99 -march=native -O3 -flto -fuse-linker-plugin test.c
```

gives these assembler instructions

```
;function a()
<+0>:   push   %rbx
<+1>:   mov    $0x1,%ebx
<+6>:   jmp    0x400453 <main+19>
<+8>:   nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
<+16>:  add    $0x1,%ebx
<+19>:  cmp    $0x80000000,%ebx
<+25>:  je     0x40046e <main+46>
<+27>:  cmp    $0xffffffff,%ebx
<+30>:  jne    0x400450 <main+16>
<+32>:  mov    $0x400614,%edi
<+37>:  callq  0x400410 <puts@plt>
<+42>:  xor    %eax,%eax
<+44>:  pop    %rbx
<+45>:  retq   
;function b()
<+46>:  mov    $0x400614,%edi
<+51>:  callq  0x400410 <puts@plt>
<+56>:  jmp    0x400450 <main+16>
```

Comment: Since this only results in a total of maybe 2 branch mispredictions in its unoptimised form it's hardly worth worrying about.

Comment: What makes you think that `b()` is better than `a()`? It has two loops, which means more code plus alignment (loops are aligned); more code and alignment are likely to cause more cache misses. And as Paul has pointed out, `a()` means maybe 2 branch mispredictions so I really don't see *why* gcc should do this optimization. Did you measure the performance improvements you can achieve with `b()`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. 
b() is reduced to a single puts(), while a() still contains the loop even though I would suspect them to be optimized away as the loops in b() are optimized away.
It's not so much a question about performance, but rather compiler behavior.

Comment: Your test isn't realistic precisely because the optimizer gets rid of the two useless loops in your second example - if your real code has useless loops, remove them. If not, your "benchmark" isn't a good benchmark and wondering about it is a waste of your time.

Comment: Apples and oranges: in b() gcc figures out that assignments to c are useless (and there is no side effect) so it might as well drop both loops. In a() there is no guarantee that a == (UINT_MAX/2) will be true exactly once..that could only be derived from a property of / and the uniqueness (and monotonicity) of the values of a. And I would be shocked to learn if gcc was able to prove that puts() cannot possibly alter the value of 'a' (by some nasty tricks of the local variables of the caller).

Comment: @user1666959: Thanks, that answers my question.
I was well aware of why the loops in b() were removed, but I wasn't aware that that puts() could have nasty side effects to a that gcc can't tell anything about.